# How to order using binance api in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to order using Binance api with the following Objective-c code.

```
- (void)order {

    double unixtime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *time = [@( floor(unixtime * 1000) ) stringValue];




    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"https://api.binance.com"];
    components.path = @"/api/v3/order";



    NSURLQueryItem *symbol     = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"symbol"     value:@"BTCUSDT"];
    NSURLQueryItem *side       = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"side"       value:@"BUY"];
    NSURLQueryItem *type       = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"type"       value:@"MARKET"];
    NSURLQueryItem *quantity   = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"quantity"   value:@"0.01"];
    NSURLQueryItem *timestamp  = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"timestamp"  value:time];
    NSURLQueryItem *recvWindow = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"recvWindow" value:@"5000"];
    components.queryItems = @[symbol,side,type,quantity,recvWindow,timestamp];



    NSURLQueryItem *signature = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"signature"
                                                            value:[self HMACStringForKey:secret dataString:components.query]];



    components.queryItems = @[symbol,side,type,quantity,recvWindow,timestamp,signature];


    NSURL *url = [components URL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:apikey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-MBX-APIKEY"];





    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                         if (response && ! error) {
                                         NSLog(@"%@",  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);
                                         } else {
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                         }

                                     }] resume];


}
```

But I get the following error.
Please let me know how to order using binance api.

```
{
    code = "-1101";
    msg = "Too many parameters; expected '6' and received '7'.";
}
```

The documentation for Binance API can be found here: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md. What am I doing wrong ?

Environment

macOS HighSierra
XCode 9.0.1
Objective-C

Comment: Which endpoint are you attempting to target?

Comment: what is endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP verb is `GET`, the documentation says you should be using `POST` for the `/api/v3/order` endpoint.

Change `[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];` to `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`

Comment: Thank you so much!